# C++ object created with new, destroyed with free(); How bad is this?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am working on modifying a relatively large C++ program, where unfortunately it is not always clear whether someone before me used C or C++ syntax (this is in the electrical engineering department at a university, and we EEs are always tempted to use C for everything, and unfortunately in this case, people can actually get away with it).

However, if someone creates an object:

`Packet* thePacket = new Packet();`

Does it matter whether it is destroyed with `delete thePacket;` or `free(thePacket);` ?

I realize that delete calls the destructor while free() does not, but Packet does not have a destructor. I am having a terrible time stuck in a memory management swamp here and I'm thinking this may be one of the many problems.

Comment: Packet has a destructor, even if you can't see it. It... gah, answer below.

Comment: The right answer is you shouldn't be deleting things. Wrap them up.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Yes it does matter.

For memory obtained using `new` you **must** use `delete`.

For memory obtained using `malloc` you **must** use `free`.

`new`  and `malloc` may use different data structures internally to keep track of what and where it has allocated memory. So in order to free memory, you have to call that corresponding function that knows about those data structures. It is however generally a bad idea to mix these two types of memory allocation in a piece of code.

Comment: @Dmitri, valgrind can help you find mismatches.

Comment: I don't see where it is a bad idea to mix new and malloc as long as you always use the corresponding delete/free method. In fact there are several reasons to use malloc/realloc/free in code which otherwise use new/delete (i.e. managing an internal buffer which should be reallocated and so on.). Someone could even use other heap management functions (i.e. HeapAlloc and friends on windows systems). Or program an own memory pool. Why not mix that?

Comment: @rstevens There's no problem mixing `new` and `malloc` -- just mismatching. However, you should consider that mixing may be a problem if it will lead you to mismatch.

Answer (score 38):

If you call `free()`, the destructor doesn't get called.

Also, there's [no guarantee that `new` and `free` operate on the same heap.](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#mixing-malloc-and-delete)

You can also override `new` and `delete` to operate specially on a particular class. If you do so, but call `free()` instead of the custom `delete`, then you miss whatever special behavior you had written into `delete`. (But you probably wouldn't be asking this question if you had done that, because you'd know what behaviors you were missing..)

Comment: Thanks. See my comment on Omnifarious' post (i was reading from bottom up)

Comment: @Dmitri, I wasn't suggesting redefining `delete` as a solution -- I was pointing out as another potential problem. I've edited my answer to make that a little clearer.

Comment: If you override the global `new` and `delete` then you *have* to use `malloc()` and `free()`.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: no, you don't. You could preallocate a chunk of contiguous memory and do your own memory management inside of it (i.e. a special memory pool), or you could use some special system call provided by your operating system (e.g. `mmap` or `HeapAlloc`). You could also simply add special accounting to `new` and `delete`, and by mismatching `new` with `free` in the calling code, your accounting wouldn't get updated correctly when you `free` the data.

Answer (score 12):

`Packet` has a destructor, even if you haven't explicitly declared one.  It has a default destructor.  The default destructor probably doesn't actually do much, but you can't count on that being the case.  It's up to the compiler what it does.

`new` and `malloc` also may have wildly different implementations.  For example, delete is always called in a context where it has perfect information about the size of the data structure it's deleting at compile time.  `free` does not have this luxury.  It's possible that the allocator that `new` is using may not store the bytes at the beginning of the memory area stating how many bytes it occupies.  This would lead `free` to do entirely the wrong thing and crash your program when freeing something allocated with `new`.

Personally, if getting people to do the right thing or fixing the code yourself is completely impossible, I would declare my own global `operator new` that called `malloc` so then `free` would definitely not crash, even though it would still not call the destructor and be generally really ugly.

Comment: Unlike all the other answers, this one describes a easy solution that doesn't require cleaning up all your code.

Answer (score 5):

In short, it is as bad as undefined behavior.

This is quiet self explanatory.

> C Standard ($7.20.3.2/2) - "The free
>   function causes the space pointed to
>   by ptr to be deallocated, that is,
>   made available for further allocation.
>   If ptr is a null pointer, no action
>   occurs. Otherwise, if the argument
>   does not match a pointer earlier
>   returned by the calloc, malloc, or
>   realloc function, or if the space has
>   been deallocated by a call to free or
>   realloc, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 4):

You are absolutely right, it is **NOT** correct. As you said yourself, free won't call the destructor. Even if Packet doesn't have an explicit destructor, it's using an inherited one.

Using `free` on an object created with `new` is like destroying only what a shallow-copy would reach. Deep-destroying NEEDS the destructor function.

Also, I'm not sure objects created with new() are on the same memory map as malloc()'d memory. They are not guaranteed to be, I think.

Answer (score 2):

> if someone creates an object:
>
> ```
> Packet* thePacket = new Packet();
> ```
>
> Does it matter whether is is destroyed with delete thePacket; or free(thePacket); ?

Yes it does matter. `free (thePacket)` would invoke Undefined Behaviour but `delete thePacket` would not and we all know Undefined Behaviour may have disastrous consequences.