# C++ How to Initialize member object?

Tags: c++

Is there some way to initialize(?) member variable c of type C in the first part of the below example?  Or must I use the new() method shown in the second part of the example?

Class B takes class A as an injected dependency.  So does class C.  Class B is additionally composed of class C.

How do I get the injected A to B's member C?

Part 1

```
class A { // ...; };

class C {
public:
    C(A &a) : a(a) {}   // constructor
};


// Does not work as is.  Want to make compiler manage C lifetime.
class B {
public:
    B(A &a);    // constructor

    C c(a);     // member variable
};

// constructor
B::B(A &a) : a(a) {
}
```

Part 2

```
// Works, but requires programmer to manage C's lifetime.
class B {
public:
    B(A &a);    // constructor

    C *c;       // member variable
};

// constructor
B::B(A &a) : a(a) {
    c = new C(a);
}
```

Several good answers below!  My apologies for the confusing example.  I have up-voted all of the good answers and questions.  Unfortunately I can only mark one answer as the accepted answer, so I am choosing the first one which gave me the "ah-ha" moment in which I saw the solution to my real problem, which was more complex than my lame example here.

Comment: Usually you don't need `new`. And you never use `new/free` in conjunction. And yes, C++ provides means to initialize objects.

Comment: [Don't use `free` with `new`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061514/c-object-created-with-new-destroyed-with-free-how-bad-is-this).

Comment: Sorry, bad example.  I don't want to use `new` at all.  Can it be done?  How?  (will edit question)

Comment: Yes it can be done, @StenSoft's answer tells you how.

Comment: Also, your class `C` doesn't have any data members called `a`.

Comment: My apologies for the incomplete example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Member variables are initialized in constructor's initialization list (before body) so you need to do that:

```
B::B(A &a)
    : c(a) // Calls constructor C(a) on member c
{}
```

Comment: I see my confusion now.  Too many trees in the forest for me to see the forest, as the saying goes.  What I really needed was: `public: B(A &a) : a(a), c(a)`.

Answer (score 3):

You almost have it:

```
class B {
public:
    B(A &a);

    C c(a); //see note 1
};

B::B(A &a) : a(a) { //see note 2
}
```

### Note 1:

There are two problems with `C c(a);` here:

1. `a` is not in scope. `a` only exists within the scope of the constructor, so `c` needs to be initialized from there.
2. Until C++11, non-static data member initializers (NSDMIs) were prohibited. Even in C++11, though, you must use an equals sign (`C c = value;`) or braces (`C c{value};`) when initializing an NSDMI.

### Note 2:

You've almost got this right:

```
B::B(A &a) : a(a)
```

You're trying to initialize a data member called `a` with the argument given to the constructor. You actually want to initialize `c` like this, not a non-existent `a`:

```
B::B(A &a) : c(a)
```

---

The lifetime of `c` will be that of the instance of the `B` class. Using dynamic memory management is certainly not necessary.

Comment: Excellent answer, as well.

Answer (score 1):

> *"How do I get the injected A to B's member C?"*

You can do so using `B`'s constructor member initializer list

```
class B {
public:
    B(A &a) : c(a) {
           // ^^^^
    }

    C c; // <<< It's not possible to initialize members in their
         //     declaration.
};
```

Comment: I see my confusion now.  Too many trees in the forest for me to see the forest, as the saying goes.  What I really needed was: `public: B(A &a) : a(a), c(a)`.  Or actually, in my real code `public: B(A &a) : a(a), c(a), d(a, c)`.

Answer (score 1):

The following:

```
C(A &a) : a(a) {}
```

will not compile since `a` (the first `a` in the initialization list) is not a member variable of `C`.

Same applies to the constructor of `B`.

Comment: My apologies for the incomplete example.  In my real problem, a is also a member.