# GLib Asynchronous Queue with non-POD objects

Tags: c++, memory-management, message-queue, glib

In a C++ program that uses GLib, it is safe to use [non-POD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c) objects with an [Asynchronous Queue](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Asynchronous-Queues.html)?

Basically the non-POD object would be passed as `gpointer data` to

```
void
g_async_queue_push (GAsyncQueue *queue,
                    gpointer data);
```

and then retrieved with

```
gpointer
g_async_queue_pop (GAsyncQueue *queue);
```

In theory this should never cause problems because a `gpointer` is just a `typedef` for `void*`, so instead of passing POD objects allocated with `g_new` and freed with `g_free` I could pass POD objects allocated with `new` and freed by `delete` (with proper type casting to avoid [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/941959/297373)). This implementation is hidden inside my class so I'm the only one in control of the queue.

However, if the queue ever has to internally deallocate a pointer (e.g if after a `g_async_queue_unref` the queue is destroyed with items still queued), it would call `g_free` for an object allocated with `new` and that is [bad for many reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4061522/297373). The [documentation for GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Memory-Allocation.html) generically says that it's important to match `g_new()` with `g_free()` and `new` with `delete`.

I know that such a mix of C++ types with a C library should be avoided, but this kind of design consideration is outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you create your `GAsyncQueue` without specifying a free function for the elements (see [`g_async_queue_new_full()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Asynchronous-Queues.html#g-async-queue-new-full)), it’s guaranteed to not free or reallocate the pointers stored in it. They are opaque as far as the queue is concerned.

You can verify this by looking at [the implementation](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/blob/98f326a0206cf8d84940cd51dfeab9cedb5d036d/glib/gasyncqueue.c#L222).

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks.